# camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); through Null pointer exception while recording video

Tags: android, video

while open camera feature in android it has throw an error of Null pointer exception and is redirecting to this line "camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);"

What to do ?

Preview file : 
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

```
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CameraVideoPOC", "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); // facing issue here
        camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                            + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you properly instantiated the holder obj ?

Comment: Have you given the permission for camera in manifest?

Comment: Yes, i had given the permission on manifest. and had debug the holder obj and it is fine. but dont find the exact solution, can someone find me the solution as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)